# ボタンのNameプロパティを受け取りたい

Tags: wpf

ボタンクリックイベント時に、クリックイベントメソッド内でボタンのNameプロパティを受け取りたいのですが、方法が分かる方がいましたらご教授をお願いします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<Button x:Name="hoge" Click="Button_Click"/>
```

などと`x:Name`で指定しておいた場合、

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var button = (System.Windows.Controls.Button)sender;
    // button.Name で "hoge"を取得できます。
    ...
}
```

のようにして、`Name`など各プロパティにアクセスできます。

```
using System.Windows.Controls;
```

をファイル先頭などに書いておけば

```
var button = (Button)sender;
```

でも可能です。

Comment: 返答ありがとうございます。
上記の方法で取得することが出来ました。